# Send silent toast from background agent in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

From my WP8 background agent I got the normal ShellToast which is working fine.

But now with WP8.1 I want the ability to send a quiet toast during certain hours (night), it should only show up in the notification center during these hours.
I've been following [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631260.aspx) but it doesn't seem to work at all. The toast isn't showing up...

Anyone that has gotten this to work yet?

Thanks

My code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SendToast();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SendToast();
}

private void SendToast()
{
    // Using the ToastText02 toast template.
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

    // Retrieve the content part of the toast so we can change the text.
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

    //Find the text component of the content
    XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

    // Set the text on the toast. 
    // The first line of text in the ToastText02 template is treated as header text, and will be bold.
    toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Heading"));
    toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Body"));

    // Set the duration on the toast
    IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
    ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

    // Create the actual toast object using this toast specification.
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    toast.ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3600);

    // Set SuppressPopup = true on the toast in order to send it directly to action center without 
    // producing a popup on the user's phone.
    toast.SuppressPopup = false;

    // Send the toast.
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

Comment: Did you enable toast notifications in the manifest? Otherwise, some could would be cool, because the given guide is fine and we can't post better code+explanations than written there.

Comment: You mean ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION? There is none for toast, right?

Comment: @robertftw Please clarify what's not working in your current code.

Comment: I got it working, I just missed the Package.appmanifest and enable toasts there. I've posted it as an answer down below, havn't been able to mark it as an answer yet (24h rule).

Comment: Where are you using background agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys! I missed the new Package.appmanifest that comes with 8.1 SL. Old ShellToast seems to work without it (I think?) but not with the new toast namespaces.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the new **Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification** API.
Sample, how to use it is here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Action-Center-Quickstart-b15089f2
And quickstart documentation is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631259.aspx

And if you want send silent notification, just set the SuppressPopup property to true:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup.aspx

**Important note** - if you want to use this API in your Silverlight 8.1 app, you need to **change the notification type in WMAppManifest.xml to WNS**, otherwise your app won't pass the certification. I've spent about a day solving this problem, it's not much obvious.

Comment: Yeah I'm using that namespace. Check my edit for the code I use. If you spot any errors lets me know.

Comment: I faced certification problem and I had to change the notification type to WNS. I would never thought about that until I saw your post :-)